# Cannot assign value of type ViewSecond to ViewFirst

Tags: ios, swift

> I try to assign UIView super class object's to other same type class object, getting error my code is below:

```
class ViewTest: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var txtName: UITextField!
      override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var first = ViewFirst()
        var second = ViewSecond()

         func c() {
            first = second
            let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
            txtName.inputView = datePicker
        }

    }

 }

class ViewFirst: UIView {  

}

class ViewSecond: UIView {  

}
```

Why needed to type cast but **txtName.inputView = datePicker** working without any type cast
Thanks

Comment: "other same type class object". No they are not. Declare your vars of type `UIView` if you want them to be same type, then you can swap values without problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong syntax. ViewSecond is not subclass or superclass to ViewFirst，even if you force cast the object like this:

```
first = second as! ViewFirst
```

you still get crash error.
So if ViewSecond is subclass to ViewFirst, just do force cast:

```
first = second as! ViewFirst
```

there will be well.

How cound I reply directlly? I am new...
Why `txtName.inputView = datePicker` without any cast type?
Because `UIDatePicker` is subClass of UIView! And then, the `UIView` is just a type define. So you have no need to do cast. For example:

```
func giveMeSomeView(view: UIView)
```

You can put it like UIButton, UIImageView.... But in the fuction, you have no idea which the exactlly view-Type, right? You just `addSubview`. Of course if you want to set something, you can have a implicit cast:

```
func giveMeSomeView(view: UIView) {
    if let imageView = view as? UIImageView {
        imageView.image = UIImage(string:"XXXX")
    }
}
```

*If there some word you could not understand, forgive it. My English is bad.*

Comment: but txtName.inputView = datePicker this code line working well without any type cast I need to know reason for type cast. Please check updated code

Comment: My both classes (ViewFirst and ViewSecond) are subclass of UIView and UIDatePicker and input accessory view also subclass of UIView. txtName.inputView = datePicker working fine without any issue or warning.

Comment: O__O "… You must undstand Swift`s speciality: inference.    txtName.inputView = datePicker.  The inputView is a property of UITextfield, and it is UIView type, so you can assign it which it is subClass of UIView. swift has not to infer right now. But you code first = second it makes swift have to decision, so the inference appear。

Comment: Thanks for your great efforts

Answer (score 0):

You should be more precise, do you have an error? Or which line doesn't work?

I guess the error is on this line :

```
first = second
```

You have to cast the object :

```
first = second as! ViewFirst
```

Comment: is this is possible without casting

Comment: Non it's not. Without casting you can just convert to super class type, so SecondView has to be a subclass of FirstView

Comment: But txtName.inputView = datePicker working without any issue

Comment: Sure, datePicker extends from UIInputView. But I found an other solution. It should works if your `var first` is type as `id`

Answer (score 0):

Please be more specific.

You can solve this problem bij making ViewSecond a subclass of ViewFirst instead of UIView.

For example:

```
class ViewFirst: UIView {

}

class ViewSecond: ViewFirst {

}
```